# Owned pointer in graph structure

Tags: graph, rust

With the generous help of the rust community I managed to get the base of a topological data structure assembled using managed pointers. This came together rather nicely and I was pretty excited about Rust in general. Then I read this [post](http://pcwalton.github.io/blog/2013/06/02/removing-garbage-collection-from-the-rust-language/) (which seems like a reasonable plan) and it inspired me to back track and try to re-assemble it using only owned pointers if possible.

This is the working version using managed pointers:

```
struct Dart<T> {
    alpha: ~[@mut Dart<T>],
    embed: ~[@mut T],
   tagged: bool
}

impl<T> Dart<T> {
    pub fn new(dim: uint) -> @mut Dart<T> {
        let mut dart = @mut Dart{alpha: ~[], embed: ~[], tagged: false};        
        dart.alpha = vec::from_elem(dim, dart);              
        return dart;
    }
    pub fn get_dim(&self) -> uint {
        return self.alpha.len();
    }   
    pub fn traverse(@mut self, invs: &[uint], f: &fn(&Dart<T>)) {
        let dim = self.get_dim();
        for invs.each |i| {if *i >= dim {return}}; //test bounds on invs vec
        if invs.len() == 2 {
            let spread:int = int::abs(invs[1] as int - invs[0] as int);
            if spread == 1 { //simple loop
                let mut dart = self;
                let mut i = invs[0];
                while !dart.tagged {
                    dart.tagged = true; 
                    f(dart);
                    dart = dart.alpha[i];
                    if i == invs[0] {i = invs[1];}
                    else {i == invs[0];}
            }   }           
            // else if spread == 2 { // max 4 cells traversed

            // }
        }
        else {
            let mut stack = ~[self];
            self.tagged = true;     
            while !stack.is_empty() {
                let mut dart = stack.pop();
                f(dart);  
                for invs.each |i| {
                    if !dart.alpha[*i].tagged {
                        dart.alpha[*i].tagged = true;
                        stack.push(dart);
}   }   }   }   }   }
```

After a few hours of chasing lifetime errors I have come to the conclusion that this may not even be possible with owned pointers due to the cyclic nature (without tying the knot as I was [warned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879287/mutable-struct-fields)). My feeble attempt at this is below. My question, is this structure possible to implement without resorting to managed pointers? And if not, is the code above considered reasonably "rusty"? (idiomatic rust). Thanks.

```
struct GMap<'self,T> {
    dim: uint,
    darts: ~[~Dart<'self,T>]
}   

struct Dart<'self,T> { 
    alpha: ~[&'self mut Dart<'self, T>], 
    embed: ~[&'self mut T], 
    tagged: bool 
}

impl<'self, T> GMap<'self, T> {
    pub fn new_dart(&'self mut self) {
        let mut dart = ~Dart{alpha: ~[], embed: ~[], tagged: false};
        let dartRef: &'self mut Dart<'self, T> = dart;  
        dartRef.alpha = vec::from_elem(self.dim, copy dartRef);
        self.darts.push(dart);              
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that using `&mut` pointers is impossible, since one can only have one such pointer in existence at a time, e.g.:

```
fn main() {
    let mut i = 0;
    let a = &mut i;
    let b = &mut i;
}
```

```
and-mut.rs:4:12: 4:18 error: cannot borrow `i` as mutable more than once at at a time
and-mut.rs:4     let b = &mut i;
                         ^~~~~~
and-mut.rs:3:12: 3:18 note: second borrow of `i` as mutable occurs here
and-mut.rs:3     let a = &mut i;
                         ^~~~~~
error: aborting due to previous error
```

One could get around the borrow checker unsafely, by either storing unsafe pointer to the memory (`ptr::to_mut_unsafe_ptr`), or indices into the `darts` member of `GMap`. Essentially, storing a single reference to the memory (in `self.darts`) and all operations have to go through it.

This might look like:

```
impl<'self, T> GMap<'self, T> {
    pub fn new_dart(&'self mut self) {
        let ind = self.darts.len();
        self.darts.push(~Dart{alpha: vec::from_elem(self.dim, ind), embed: ~[], tagged: false});
    }
}
```

`traverse` would need to change to either be a method on `GMap` (e.g. `fn(&mut self, node_ind: uint, invs: &[uint], f: &fn(&Dart<T>))`), or at least take a `GMap` type.

(On an *entirely* different note, there is library support for [external iterators](http://static.rust-lang.org/doc/core/iterator.html), which are far more composable than the internal iterators (the ones that take a closure). So defining one of these for `traverse` may (or may not) make using it nicer.)

Comment: Seems like the overhead of the managed pointer version (GC or RC) might be worth it in this case. If I use a map or hash table to keep the darts straight, there's going to be some overhead there anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Unless using a map and owned pointers gets me the ability to traverse in parallel...not sure yet.